# How do you appeal a close decision?

Tags: support

Specifically *my* [question](https://superuser.com/questions/183446/how-do-i-get-emoji)'s closure. It's not about mobile phones at all, it's just that I didn't know it was being closed at the time so I had no chance to "defend" it.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question just needed a little trimming down to exactly what the problem is, was earlier too heavy on the mobile phone and Twitter

Comment: Also note that it doesn't have to be case-closed, if you edit to make it on-topic I'll happily open it up for you!

Answer (score 3):

The close reason is key. Editing for clarity and focus is the major option to look at.

#### Off-topic

Edit the question to be relevant to the accepted topics for Super User. If it's about mobiles, eReaders or other electronic devices, but are not connected to the desktop or laptop, it's not on.

#### Subjective and argumentative

If it was closed as subjective and argumentative, either trim the fat and boil it down to a specific problem that needs fixing or give it up.

#### Not  a real question

Edit in plenty of details and narrow the question scope to less than a grab bag of thoughts plucked from the clouds.

Comments are helpful, but the question content is the most vital aspect.

Answer (score 0):

**I've found the "Flag" link.**

I'm assuming this is the correct avenue.

Comment: You can either flag it or post the question here and mention why you feel it needs to be contested.

Comment: Also, you need to be lot more specific,your question does not have relevant details.

Comment: The (now) edited question is soo much better and cleaner than the original